# ACF Add fields values to newly inserted post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with ACF plugin.

```
function add_custom_post(/* .. */){}
     $post_id = wp_insert_post(array(
      //....
   ));

   update_field('fieldname', $value, $post_id);

   return (bool)$post_id;
}
```

Symptoms: `<?php the_field('fieldname'); ?>` does not return value in template;
Fields are saved and values are visible in wp-admin. After clicking "Update" to post, above starts working fine.
From what I noticed it does not create post `key` if I use Update field and backoffice save creates them.

How to add value programmatically to newly added post?

EDIT:
It would seem like i have to create `key` for field in post. No idea how.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this instead of using `update_field()`:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'fieldname', $value);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_fieldname', 'field_' . uniqid()); // `uniqid() is a native PHP function. This is also how ACF creates the field keys
```

Also, depending where you are retrieving the value, you may also have to pass the post id.

```
the_field('fieldname', $post_id);
```

Comment: Testing it atm!. I'm retrieving in theloop.

Comment: Does not work. Still values are not retrieved. But are visible in wp-admin. Still need to re-save product in admin, to make them visible

Comment: Ok. Maybe then you need to go through this process - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/

Comment: Or, just use `get_post_meta()`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with following, which works for me:

```
function edu_acf_getValue($fieldname, $post_id = false){
    if($post_id === false) $post_id = get_the_ID ();
    if(($value = get_field($fieldname, $post_id)))
        return $value;
    $value = get_post_meta($post_id, $fieldname);
    return $value[0];
}
function edu_acf_updateValue($fieldname, $value, $post_id){
    $field_key = 'field_' . uniqid();
    update_post_meta($post_id, $fieldname, $value);
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$fieldname, $field_key);
    update_field($field_key, $value, $post_id);
}
```

Comment: How could I use this with repeater fields?

Answer (score 0):

use following to retrieve ACF field values:

```
    get_field('fieldname',$post_id);
```

Comment: Does not work if post was not added via wp-admin